# how to use substring in batch program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file which contains values like below

```
10AB2CDEFG12345
10AB5CDEFG894567
```

From the above I want only the 4 characters(alphanumeric) after 10 which in the above case is

```
AB2C and AB5C.
```

Doing it for a set value like

```
set tmp=10AB2CDEFG12345
@echo %tmp:~2%
```

gives me `AB2CDEFG12345`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
set var=10AB2CDEFG12345
set "var=%var:~2,4%"
echo %var%
```

Look at `help set` for more help.

Comment: +1 Didn't know it's possible.  I will just edit to make it clearer.

Comment: The above worked just fine but can you help me figure out how I can run the above against a file with such values.The input should be the file name.

Comment: @Sankasu this answer is finished. Enhancing questions does not correspond to the SO rules. But you might simply make a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing it:

```
set tmp=10AB2CDEFG12345
@echo %tmp:~2,-9%
@echo %tmp:~2,4%
```